# how to access a variable and called a class method at the same time

Tags: php

Hmmm,not sure how to do this

i have a public variable

```
public $meta;
```

I'm calling the method in my application like this

```
$auth->meta_data('rental_access');
```

Now I'm curious is to how I can get the information from it. How can I access the $meta variable information based on the switch logic from the method?

In my application I want to use the information from the $meta variable to make some more logic statements hmmm something like

```
if ($auth->meta-data('rental_access') == 1) { //or maybe have it look for a true/false thing
    //do this
} else {
    // then do this
}
```

Comment: Does `->db->row_count` execute the `$sql` string directly? That looks a bit odd. You are probably missing some ->db call, which returns a query $result handle for the $sql.

Comment: this class extends a parent class that loads in instantiations of my db class. The queries are correct, I was just trying to be dynamic with my method instead of making methods for each of my meta_data values in my database

Comment: I'm not disputing if the SQL query is correct. I'm wondering if the database ever sees them. That's a very atypical function signature for a row_count method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid combining that explicitely. Rather use the tried and proven *fluent interface* approach. You simply make each method `return $this`:

```
function meta_data($item) {
    ...

    return $this;
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
if ($auth->meta_data("rental_access")->meta == 2) {
```

It's usually used for calling multiple functions in a chains. But this likewise acceptable.

Obviously this is only applicable to procedures which don't already `return` a result of their own.

Comment: i get Notice: Trying to get property of non-object hmmm

Comment: Then you didn't adapt the `return $this;` line. But you should fix the database query issue first anyway.

Comment: I returned $this and did an echo $auth->meta_data('rental_access')->meta; The query is ok

Comment: i included my class for a broader look. In my get_settings() I am using the same query layout which return information, I had a get_rental_access() before which all it did was make $this-meta = to the results and i added the method into the constructor which seemed to work, but i have more than one value i need from my meta_data table which I wanted one method to take care off

Comment: I'm throwing in the support towel. No idea what could be the problem then.

Comment: thank you, I'll play with it. I know what you are saying is correct by chaining methods. I have done it before but not with variables. I am thinking that maybe the SWITCH statement isn't running thru

Comment: As said, `$this->meta = $result[$item];` might be able to replace the whole switch statement. Other than that try `print_r($result);` in its place. Maybe the database returns empty fields?

Comment: hmmm, lemme see what i get with that

Answer (score 0):

Why not modify your `meta_data()` method, so it returns the new value of your `meta` property :

```
public function meta_data($item)
{
    // your existing code, here

    return $this->meta;
}
```

And, then, call it storing the returned value into a variable :

```
$new_value = $auth->meta_data('rental_access');
```

Comment: i tried, and did something like $e = $auth->meta_data('rental_access'); and echoed out $e but I', not getting a value outputted